# C - error: array type has incomplete element type in a extern struct declaration

Tags: c, struct, extern

I have next code:

```
// FILE: HEADERS.h
extern struct viaje viajes[];
extern struct cliente clientes[];

// FILE: STRUCTS.c
struct viaje {
    char identificador[30+1];
    char ciudadDestino[30+1];
    char hotel[30+1];
    int numeroNoches;
    char tipoTransporte[30+1];
    float precioAlojamiento;
    float precioDesplazamiento;
};

struct cliente {
    char dni[30+1];
    char nombre[30+1];
    char apellidos[30+1];
    char direccion[30+1];
    int totalViajes;
    struct viaje viajes[50];
} clientes[20];
```

When I try to complile code I get next error: `error: array type has incomplete element type in a extern struct declaration` and I do not know why could it be. I have tried also include header after Structs definition and I do not get any error, but it is wrong, the correct way is Define -> Declare, not Declare -> Define.

Why could it be?. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding your design, why the `extern` in the first place with the current design? If a consumer of `HEADERS.h` pulls in only what you show here, what are you expecting they do with those externs? I ask because, without the formal definitions, the only answer is "not much". Is there a reason you don't just move the structure definitions (not the variables; just the struct defs) to said-same header prior to your externs?

Comment: No, there is no reason. Only reason is due to I learn to declare Structs for this way, this is only reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define or declare an instance of a struct, that struct needs to be defined first.  Otherwise, the compiler can't figure out the size of the structure or what its members are.

You need to put the struct definitions first in your header file before the `extern` declarations:

```
struct viaje {
    char identificador[30+1];
    char ciudadDestino[30+1];
    char hotel[30+1];
    int numeroNoches;
    char tipoTransporte[30+1];
    float precioAlojamiento;
    float precioDesplazamiento;
};

struct cliente {
    char dni[30+1];
    char nombre[30+1];
    char apellidos[30+1];
    char direccion[30+1];
    int totalViajes;
    struct viaje viajes[50];
};   // note that there are no instances defined here

extern struct viaje viajes[];
extern struct cliente clientes[];
```

Then your .c file would contain the instances:

```
// Changed size viajes from 20 to 50
struct viaje viajes[50];
struct cliente clientes[20];
```

Comment: Oh, ok, I am goint to try this option and I tell you, thank you. One question: there is defined twice that clientes is an array of 20 elements, it is right? or the size of 'viajes' inside the structure 'cliente' could be omitted?

Comment: @JuMoGar Yes, the size can be omitted in the `extern` declaration.  What's required is that the definition has a size and/or an initializer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself well: I mean that within the structure 'cliente' is defined 'struct viaje viajes[20]', and then, in the .c file the same thing is instantiated again: 'struct viaje viajes[ 20] ', could not one of these two be omitted? or delete the size within 'client' (something like: 'struct trip travel []')? or only put inside struct 'cliente' the var 'viajes' no more? Thank you. I have tryed your code and works fine, thank you so much for the solution.

Comment: @JuMoGar All array elements inside of a struct must be given a value *unless* it is the last field.  In that case, the struct itself can't be part of an array and must be allocated on the stack one instance at a time.

Comment: @JuMoGar The `struct viaje` array inside of `struct cliente` is completely separate form the `struct viaje` array defined in the .c file.  If you want both, keep both, otherwise remove whatever you don't need.

Comment: I only use 'struct viaje'  inside 'struct cliente.viajes' so... I must delete `extern struct viaje viajes[];` and `struct viaje viajes[50];` right? (I do not want two separated struct, One is son of the other) Thank you for your help.